# Edit PHP file for Joomla 2.5 Module K2 Content

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I'm trying to edit the K2 content module by changing the file:

```
/modules/mod_k2_content/tmpl/Default/default.php
```

Basically I need a `div` to wrap around:

```
<a class="moduleItemCategory">
```

Somewhere near line 128.

But when I change the file nothing is changed on the webpage...

Is this the right file?

I'm not using sub-templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that there is a template override for this file. Template overrides are simply a duplicate of your **default.php** (name may sometimes be different) which will be located in the directory below and is used to perform edits to the view of an extension without editing the core file.

```
templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/mod_k2_content/default.php
```

If you see this file there, then you will need to edit this one

Comment: You got it! Old site (old memory).